# Google Analytics segment of users with single sessions not working

Tags: google-analytics, advanced-segments

When I tried to get users segment who just had a single session (In lifetime) and their conversions, I am surprised to see that more than 50% of such users have transactions. However, when I saw User explorer, for these customers, I can see multiple sessions for each.

For reference, The conditions I specified

[[image: Condition for creating segment[1]]

Then When I went to User explorer,forget about user, each client had multiple sessions. Where am I doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Count of Sessions** is a dimension not a metrics as we may expect it to be, it is incremented in the cookie with each session and is passed in GA as such. To elaborate let's follow below example :

```
User A - Visit's 1st time | Count Of Session =1 | Transacted
User A - Visit's 2nd time | Count Of Session =2 | Didn't Transact
User A - Visit's 3rd time | Count Of Session =3 | Didn't Transact
```

This user will still be included in your report (despite saying you only need users with one session) because it's first visit has 1 in Count Of Session Dimension.

For your case **Sessions To Transactions** would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. But it is still not solving the issue. I defined the sessions to transaction as 1 in the condition but I still see many users who made Singe transaction with multiple sessions before they make any purchase. I even used Days to Transaction. But for some reason it is still showing users with 5-6 sessions & 7 days before they purchase something. Should I use a combination of the both?